# Call the method in an internal function c#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, function

i want to pass string value from function to internal function.

```
private void datagrid_customer_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < datagrid_customer.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString((datagrid_customer.SelectedCells[3].Column.GetCellContent(datagrid_customer.SelectedItem) as TextBlock).Text) == Convert.ToString((datagrid_customer.SelectedCells[1].Column.GetCellContent(datagrid_customer.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text))
        {
            ...
            string a = (b + c + d).ToString();       
        }
 }
```

I want to pass `a` to another function

```
datagrid_customer.SelectAll();

for (int i = 0; i < datagrid_customer.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToString((datagrid_customer.SelectedCells[43].Column.GetCellContent(datagrid_customer.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text) == "0")
    {
        ...
         txt_f1.Text = a ;
    }
}
```

I need to `txt_f1.text = a` but i dont have access to use `a`.

what should I do?

Comment: Declare `string a` outside the scope of that `if` statement.  You can still assign it inside that `if` statement, but it goes out of scope if you declare it there also.  See the duplicate post I linked above.

Comment: `string a` will then become visible to the rest of your code in `datagrid_customer_SelectionChanged`.  Declare `string a;` right before your first loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created the other function, then you can pass it as a parameter to you function like:

```
int OtherFunction(string a)
{
    // your code here
}
```

and then simply call your function like:

```
OtherFunction(a);
```

If the other method is not something you have created like a method of a click event or something, then you should make your variable global that would be valid in both scopes:

```
public string a = ""; // in your main class
```

and then:

```
void function1()
{
    //some code
    a = "some value";
    //some code
}


int OtherFunction()
{
    // you have access to a in here to
    textBox1.Text = a;
}
```

**EDIT:** (a showcase of declaring the variable in your own example)

```
string a = "";  //declare it here before (outside) method not inside it
private void datagrid_customer_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < datagrid_customer.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString((datagrid_customer.SelectedCells[3].Column.GetCellContent(datagrid_customer.SelectedItem) as TextBlock).Text) == Convert.ToString((datagrid_customer.SelectedCells[1].Column.GetCellContent(datagrid_customer.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text))
        {
            ...
            a = (b + c + d).ToString();       
        }
 }
```

Comment: when i create function and paste my code then show me error in datagirid . program Do not know the datagrid

Comment: Most errors were fixed but when i return "a" show me error **"cannot implicitly convert type  string to int"**

Comment: @emadshn you should parse it to int: `int q = int.Parse(a);`

Comment: when click button , program is crash and show me error in " int.parse(a); "  **input string was not in a correct format.**

Comment: well then the value of `a` is not numeric and can't be parsed as `int`, for example, if `a = "123"`, `int q = int.Parse(a);` will work and `q = 123` but if `a = "x12";` then it can't be parsed as int. however its not related to this question.

Comment: Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani my value like this **123.123**  have Point but dont have character.

Comment: @ Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani  thank bro  <3

Comment: point is not valid for int, then try parsing it to double and to make sure trim it before parsing like: `double q = double.Parse(a.Trim())` so q will be `123.123` if you want int then ` int q = (int)double.Parse(a.Trim());` then q will be `123`

Comment: Look at this error http://uupload.ir/files/qw3n_annotation.png